# sort divs with jQuery using a tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort divs with jQuery and I have this html:

```
<div id="container">
    <button type="button" id="sort">sort</button>
    <div class="entry" id="lala">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://lala">lala</a>
        <span class="times">4</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="entry" id="lele">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://lele.com">lele.com</a>
        <span class="times">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry" id="lolo">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://lolo">lolo.com</a>
        <span class="times">2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use the class "times" value to sort the "entry" divs. My javascript function doesn't work because `a.child is undefined`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
        var elems = $('#container').children('.entry').remove();
        elems.sort(function(a,b){
            var valueA = parseInt(a.children(".times").text());
            var valueB = parseInt(b.children(".times").text());
            return (valueA < valueB) ? -1 : (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        $('#container').append(elems);
    });
});
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally used a different method. I created the attribute `data-sort` in the `.entry` divs and I used this javascript function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
        var elems = $('#container').children('.entry').remove();
        elems.sort(function(a,b){
            var a = parseInt($(a).attr("data-sort"));
            var b = parseInt($(b).attr("data-sort"));
            return (a > b) ? -1 : (a < b) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        $('#container').append(elems);
    });
});
```

I still don't know how to use a tag value to sort divs but this method actually works.

Comment: Check out my answer. That plugin lets you do what you want and is quite flexible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small plugin [available here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121171727/http://james.padolsey.com:80/snippets/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) that lets you easily do this like:

```
$('#sort').click(function() {
  $('.entry').sortElements(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.times').text() > $(b).find('.times').text() ? 1 : -1;
  });
});
```

#Here's an example using the plugin#

```js
/**
 * jQuery.fn.sortElements
 * --------------
 * @param Function comparator:
 *   Exactly the same behaviour as [1,2,3].sort(comparator)
 *
 * @param Function getSortable
 *   A function that should return the element that is
 *   to be sorted. The comparator will run on the
 *   current collection, but you may want the actual
 *   resulting sort to occur on a parent or another
 *   associated element.
 *
 *   E.g. $('td').sortElements(comparator, function(){
 *      return this.parentNode;
 *   })
 *
 *   The <td>'s parent (<tr>) will be sorted instead
 *   of the <td> itself.
 */
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function() {

  var sort = [].sort;

  return function(comparator, getSortable) {

    getSortable = getSortable || function() {
      return this;
    };

    var placements = this.map(function() {

      var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
        parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

        // Since the element itself will change position, we have
        // to have some way of storing its original position in
        // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
        nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
          document.createTextNode(''),
          sortElement.nextSibling
        );

      return function() {

        if (parentNode === this) {
          throw new Error(
            "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
          );
        }

        // Insert before flag:
        parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
        // Remove flag:
        parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

      };

    });

    return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
      placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
    });

  };

})();


$('#sort').click(function() {
  $('.entry').sortElements(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.times').text() > $(b).find('.times').text() ? 1 : -1;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button type="button" id="sort">sort</button>
  <div class="entry" id="lala">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://lala">lala</a>
    <span class="times">4</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="entry" id="lele">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://lele.com">lele.com</a>
    <span class="times">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="entry" id="lolo">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://lolo">lolo.com</a>
    <span class="times">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

i bet there shold be an easier way than this. I just wake up

```
$('#sort').click(function(){
    var arr = {};
$.each($('.entry'), function(ii, n){
    //console.log(n);
    arr[$(this).find('.times').html()] = n;
});
  $(arr).sort();
    $('.entry').remove();
    $.each (arr, function(i, v){
        $(v).appendTo('#container');
    })
})
```

[jsfiddle.net example](https://jsfiddle.net/f15rcc6b/)